# VBA saveas overwrite doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I have a file a need to overwrite everyday, but I get a run time error (1004) and it eon't save it.
Do you have any idea why or what can I do with that?

What the code does:

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts=false
Dim wrk as workbook
Set wrk = workbooks.add
Wrk.saveas filename:="path\filename.xlsx"
Application.displayAlerts=true
[rest of the code]
```

I get a debug on the saveas line.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a period before the filename?

Comment: I don't really have a period there, I just couldn't write the path here.

Comment: So you really have something structured like `"[the path]\[filename].xlsx"`?

Comment: It's written as a regular path "folder\folder\folder\filename.xlsx"

Comment: (a) OK then - it was just a likely error if you had an incorrect filename by placing a `.` somewhere instead of a backslash - may as well check for the obvious errors first.  (b) Do you have the file open when you try to save the new file with the same name?  (c) If the file is on a network, does another user have the file open?

Comment: Yeah the path is fine I checked multiple times before I wrote the post. And the file is closed and not used by anyone else

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error 1004 message you are getting?  (1004 is used for lots of messages)

Comment: Cannot access file

Comment: Do you have permission to save the file at the path you use? Try saving a file manually in the target folder to check that.

Comment: What is the actual complete path and file string? Replace the username and folder's name with dummy values for privacy reason.

Comment: Yes It lets me save it manually

Comment: So if it crashes, and you select "End", it allows you to save the file manually to the exact same path/filename as is in the `filename` parameter?

Comment: FWIW - I have managed to find ways of getting lots of different 1004 messages using your code.  The only way I have so far managed to get a message of `Cannot access 'filename.xlsx'.` (which is what I assume your "Cannot access file" was short for) is by having the file open in another instance of Excel.

Comment: I ended up using another workbook to run the macros on and then save it where I needed and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the existing file. before opening another file with the same name.

```
Sub Test_Module()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Dim wrk As Workbook
        Set wrk = Workbooks.Add
        wrk.SaveAs Filename:="C:\filename.xlsx"
        wrk.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```